# Python pandas: Is there a way to flag all records of a category which has one particular sub-category?

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently working on a dataset which has information on total sales for each product id and product sub category. For eg, let us consider that there are three products 1, 2 and 3. There are three product sub categories - A,B,C, one or two or all of which may comprise the products 1, 2 and 3. For instance, I have included a sample table below:

[image]

Now, I would like to add  a flag column 'Flag' which can assign 1 or 0 to each product id depending on whether that product id is contains record of product sub category 'C'. If it does contain 'C', then assign 1 to the flag column. Otherwise, assign 0. Below is the desired output.

[image]

I am currently not able to do this in pandas. Could you help me out? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use pandas transform and contains.  transform applies the lambda function to all rows in the dataframe.

```
txt="""ID,Sub-category,Sales
1,A,100
1,B,101
1,C,102
2,B,100
2,C,101
3,A,102
3,B,100"""
df = pd.read_table(StringIO(txt), sep=',') 
#print(df)

list_id=list(df[df['Sub-category'].str.contains('C')]['ID'])
df['flag']=df['ID'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x in list_id else 0 )
print(df)
```

output:

```
ID Sub-category  Sales  flag
0   1            A    100     1
1   1            B    101     1
2   1            C    102     1
3   2            B    100     1
4   2            C    101     1
5   3            A    102     0
6   3            B    100     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
Flag = [ ]
for i in dataFrame["Product sub-category]:
     if i == "C":
          Flag.append(1)
     else:
          Flag.append(0)
```

So you have a list called "Flag" and can add it to your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a temporary column, `isC` to check for your condition. Then check for the number of `isC`'s inside every "Product Id" group (with `.groupby(...).transform`).

```
check = (
    df.assign(isC=lambda df: df["Product Sub-category"] == "C")
      .groupby("Product Id").isC.transform("sum")
)
df["Flag"] = (check > 0).astype(int)
```